# Kubernetes add ca certificate to pods' trust root

Tags: ssl, docker, certificate, kubernetes

In my 10-machines bare-metal Kubernetes cluster, one service needs to call another https-based service which is using a self-signed certificate.
However, since this self-signed certificate is not added into pods' trusted root ca, the call failed saying can't validate x.509 certificate.

All pods are based on ubuntu docker images. However the way to add ca cert to trust list on ubuntu (using dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates) is not working on this pod any longer. Of course even I succeeded adding the ca cert to trust root on one pod, it's gone when another pod is kicked.

I searched Kubernetes documents, and surprised not found any except configuring cert to talk to API service which is not what I'm looking for. It should be quite common scenario if any secure channel needed between pods. Any ideas?

Answer (score 23):

**Updated Edit read option 3:**

I can think of 3 options to solve your issue if I was in your scenario:

## Option 1)

**(The only complete solution I can offer, my other solutions are half solutions unfortunately, credit to Paras Patidar/the following [site](https://medium.com/@paraspatidar/add-ssl-tls-certificate-or-pem-file-to-kubernetes-pod-s-trusted-root-ca-store-7bed5cd683d) :)**

1. Add certificate to config map:
   lets say your pem file is my-cert.pem 
   `kubectl -n <namespace-for-config-map-optional> create configmap ca-pemstore — from-file=my-cert.pem`
2. Mount configmap as volume to exiting CA root location of container:
   mount that config map’s file as one to one file relationship in volume mount in directory /etc/ssl/certs/ as file for example

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cacheconnectsample
spec:
      containers:
      - name: cacheconnectsample
        image: cacheconnectsample:v1
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ca-pemstore
          mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/my-cert.pem
          subPath: my-cert.pem
          readOnly: false
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        command: [ "dotnet" ]
        args: [ "cacheconnectsample.dll" ]
      volumes:
      - name: ca-pemstore
        configMap:
          name: ca-pemstore
```

So I believe the idea here is that /etc/ssl/certs/ is the location of tls certs that are trusted by pods, and the subPath method allows you to add a file without wiping out the contents of the folder, which would contain the k8s secrets.

 If all pods share this mountPath, then you might be able to add a pod present and configmap to every namespace, but that's in alpha and is only helpful for static namespaces. (but if this were true then all your pods would trust that cert.)

## Option 2)

**(Half solution/idea + doesn't exactly answer your question but solves your problem, I'm fairly confident will work in theory, that will require research on your part, but I think you'll find it's the best option :)**

In theory you should be able to leverage cert-manager + external-dns + Lets Encrypt Free + a public domain name to replace the self signed cert with a Public Cert.
(there's cert-manager's end result is to auto gen a k8s tls secret signed by Lets Encrypt Free in your cluster, they have a dns01 challenge that can be used to prove you own the cert, which means that you should be able to leverage that solution even without an ingress / even if the cluster is only meant for private network.)

## Option 3)

**Edit: (After gaining more hands on experience with Kubernetes)**

I believe that switchboard.op's answer is probably the best/should be the accepted answer. This "can" be done at runtime, but I'd argue that it should never be done at runtime, doing it at runtime is super hacky and full of edge cases/there's not a universal solution way of doing it.

Also it turns out that my Option 1 doing it is only half correct.
mounting the ca.crt on the pod alone isn't enough. After that file is mounted on the pod you'd need to run a command to trust it. And that means you probably need to override the pods startup command. Example you can't do something like connect to database (the default startup command) and then update trusted CA Certs's command. You'd have to override the startup file to be a hand jammed, overwrite the default startup script, update trusted CA Certs's, connect to the database. And the problem is Ubuntu,  RHEL, Alpine, and others have different locations where you have to mount the CA Cert's and sometimes different commands to trust the CA Certs so a universal at runtime solution that you can apply to all pods in the cluster to update their ca.cert isn't impossible, but would require tons of if statements and mutating webhooks/complexity. (a hand crafted per pod solution is very possible though if you just need to be able to dynamically update it for a single pod.)

switchboard.op's answer is the way I'd do it if I had to do it. Build a new custom docker image with your custom ca.cert being trusted baked into the image. This is a universal solution, and greatly simplifies the YAML side. And it's relatively easy to do on the docker image side.

Comment: Method 1 helped me. Thanks for that. I used `Secret` rather than `ConfigMap` to deploy the root CA certificate.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to bake the cert in at buildtime, edit your Dockerfile adding the commands to copy the cert from the build context and update the trust. You could even add this as a layer to something from docker hub etc.

```
COPY my-cert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

If you're trying to update the trust at runtime things get more complicated. I haven't done this myself, but you might be able to create a `configMap` containing the certificate, mount it into your container at the above path, and then use an entrypoint script to run `update-ca-certificates` before your main process.

Comment: The main disadvantage id the `update-ca-certificates` at startup like that is that it will likely fail if the container is not running as root... initContainers is another, more complex option.

Comment: @GertvandenBerg I think you're misunderstanding something. update-ca-certificates would introduce a limitation of running as root, if this was run on a live pod, but that's not what he's talking about. He's talking about running that command during docker image build time (that's perfectly fine, because they let you temp be root during 1 stage of the build of the custom container to temp get elevated rights), then become non-root in the published container image.

Comment: @neokyle You are correct yes... It might be possible to get update-ca-certificates to run without root with some strategic emptyDir volumes and an init container... (I think I missed that it was in the Dockerfile) (Dockerfile is better if the cert is available at build-time)

Comment: I am getting this error with building the dockerfile after adding your suggestion: "failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/ca-certificates.crt.tmp.XXXXXX’: No such file or directory", Could you help?

Comment: this option seems to be quite limiting, meaning that the same deployable artifacts would have to hold a 1:1 relation between private CA and docker image 

while it should be agnostic, so that it can be deployed to multiple different network configurations and different private certificate authorities

Comment: What @JoelAlmeida says.  The container image should be generic.  I think the only real solution is an initContainer mounting added CA certs to appropriate place and running update-ca-certificates, and then copying the whole /etc/pki/ca-trust dir in to an emptyDir for mounting in the later container.  I thought you maybe could make that whole directory into a Secrets and just mount that, but it exceeds 1MB.  The nice thing about an initContainer with update-ca-certificates is it would work for whatever - java, openssl, mail servers, that cam along later.

Answer (score 8):

Just for curiosity, here is an example of manifest utilizing the init container approach.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo
data:
  # in my case it is CloudFlare CA used to sign certificates for origin servers
  origin_ca_rsa_root.pem: |
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    ...
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: demo
  labels:
    name: demo
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
  initContainers:
  - name: init
    # image: ubuntu
    # command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    # args: ["apt -qq update && apt -qq install -y ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates && cp -r /etc/ssl/certs/* /artifact/"]
    # # alternative image with preinstalled ca-certificates utilities
    image: grafana/alpine:3.15.4
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args: ["update-ca-certificates && cp -r /etc/ssl/certs/* /artifact/"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: demo
      # note - we need change extension to crt here
      mountPath: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/origin_ca_rsa_root.crt
      subPath: origin_ca_rsa_root.pem
      readOnly: false
    - name: tmp
      mountPath: /artifact
      readOnly: false
  containers:
  - name: demo
    # note - even so init container is alpine base, and this one is ubuntu based everything still works
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
      - name: tmp
        mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
        readOnly: false
  volumes:
    - name: demo
      configMap:
        name: demo
    # will be used to pass files between init container and actual container
    - name: tmp
      emptyDir: {}
```

and its usage:

```bash
kubectl apply -f demo.yml
kubectl exec demo -c demo -- curl --resolve foo.bar.com:443:10.0.14.14 https://foo.bar.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json
kubectl delete -f demp.yml
```

notes:

- replace foo.bar.com to your domain name
- replace 10.0.14.14 to ingress controller cluster IP
- you may want to add -vv flag to see more details

Indeed it is kind of ugly and monstrous, but at least it does work and is proof of concept. Workarounds with simple ConfigMap do not work because curl reads ca-certificates.crt, which is not modified in that approach.

Comment: not all heroes wear a cap! thx

Comment: I don't like it but I am not seeing a better way, up

Answer (score 2):

I came up against this same problem and the options presented here were all good starting points. The initContainers method was promising but there were some application specific problems that worked against me there. In the end this method using a lifecycle hook is what worked for me.

1. Create a configMap from a cert file with *only one* cert, the root CA I need to trust:

```
kubectl -n my-namespace create configmap my-cert --from-file=root_ca_only.crt
```

2. Add the configMap as a volume to my deployment:

```
...
volumes:
  - name: my-cert
    configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: my-cert
...
```

3. Mount the cert in my container to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

```
...
volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root_ca_only.crt
          name: my-cert
          subPath: root_ca_only.crt
...
```

4. Use a postStart lifeCycle hook to run update-ca-certificates, I needed a delay for some application specific things but I'll leave it here in case someone else has the same problem:

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - sleep 10; update-ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 0):

You could update entire trusted CA by doing something like

```
rootCA1="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEYzCCA0ugA ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
all my root certs ...
"

mkdir -p myhost-files
curl https://ccadb.my.salesforce-sites.com/mozilla/IncludedRootsPEMTxt?TrustBitsInclude=Websites -o myhost-files/ca-certificates.crt
echo "$rootCA1" >> myhost-files/ca-certificates.crt
kubectl create configmap myhost-files --from-file=myhost-files --save-config --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Update helm chart values.yaml

```
    extraVolumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
        subPath: ca-certificates.crt
        name: myhost-files
    # extraVolumes: []
    extraVolumes:
      - name: myhost-files
        configMap:
          name: host-files
```

See other answers for simple deploy mount.

Note that Fedora/RHEL based is in this folder
/etc/pki/ca-trust

Some Functions you can expand as well for Debian/Fedora is you want to update it with additional files. I can't remember if root ca trust gets blown away on apt upgrade, probably on updates but not sure.

```
add_ca_crt_debian(){
  sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates  # This pkg is usually installed
  echo "debian"
  echo "${old_root_ca_crt}" | sudo tee  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/${old_cert_file_name}
  echo "${root_ca_crt}" | sudo tee  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/${cert_file_name}
  sudo update-ca-certificates
}

add_ca_crt_fedora(){
  echo "fedora"
  echo "${old_root_ca_crt}" | sudo tee  /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/${old_cert_file_name}
  echo "${root_ca_crt}" | sudo tee  /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/${cert_file_name}
  sudo update-ca-trust
}
```