# Add self signed cert to k8s

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I have problem with cert on my k8s.
In basic words: I want to have access to public resource which use https. But in my network , network guys want to analyze every traffic and they use their own cert between firewall and k8s (self signed) and public cert form firewall to outside resource.

[image]

How can i add to k8s this cert to be trusted ?

Comment: does this question answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968414/kubernetes-add-ca-certificate-to-pods-trust-root

Comment: I need to  try this, but solution form this post is based on modification every deployment (adding cert form secret/configmap). Better will be global solution (cluster level)

Comment: @lukisp have you found a right solution for yourself?